Ubuntu 24.04LTS Desktop - customization installer
Hello, I am creating a customized distribution based on the official 24.04 LTS ISO. I've made all the changes in the OS itself, but now I want to modify the installer. I've done similar modifications to Calamares on Lubuntu 22.04, but I'm unable to find information on how to do this on the newer version.
